# NPM dependency using upper case import causing build failure

Tags: javascript, npm, build

In my Angular project, one of the dependencies is using Upper Case import

> from "./CSSToMatrix"

```
export { parse, parseMat, toMat, getDistElementMatrix, caculateMatrixDist, getElementMatrix, createMatrix, } from "./CSSToMatrix";
```

But if you look at the folder structure of node_module, you will find the file name is in Title Case

> CssToMatrix.d.ts

[image]

If I build the app on my Mac, it works fine, but fails in Linux machine, because it follows strict file name check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was third party library, I could not do anything from my side. When I checked source code of library, I could see new version with this exact fix.

[library commit](https://github.com/daybrush/css-to-mat/commit/4cee5677eb182a1253fb67ebf53c0a5b71dada0c)

After bumping up the version, everything worked fine.